# AWS SAM sync keeps deploying all of my functions

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam

I'm trying to speed up my AWS Lambda deployment by using the `sam sync` command.

It does sort of what it says it's supposed to do - it kicks off deployments of the code only when I press save. The problem I'm having is that it still deploys ALL my functions, even though I am only touching one line in one lambda.

Here's my setup:
Main stack
-Substack A (only infra. Also creates two layers that I use in the Lambdas)
-Substack B (Lambda 1)
-Substack C (Lambda 2-6)

Runtime Node JS (20+)
Typescript

When I change something very inconspicious, like adding a character in a console.log command in Lambda 3, sam sync will deploy Lambda 1-6.

What i thought would happen (and would really speed things up) is that only Lambda 3 would be deployed. This is going to be a nightmare once I start adding more lambdas to my solution...

How can I make my sam sync only redeploy only the Lambda I changed code in? (or at least a minimum of impacted Lambdas if I change common code)

I have tried to narrow the scope of what sam sync is looking at by adding the `--code` and `--resource-id` Lambda 3 paramters to the sync command.